# Why do I get heap outOfMemory exception?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I'm trying to allocate a large matrix (around 10GB). I'm working on 64 bit machine with a 64 bit JVM. My process then should have `2^64` bytes available and I've set the JVM heap size to be 128G (I have 16GB of RAM in my machine if that matters). My understanding was that I should get the memory from the OS and that unneeded matrix cells would be swapped out by the OS. However I'm getting the above exception.

Edit:

This is how I'm defining the matrix:

```
Jama.Matrix A = new Matrix(num_words, num_documents);
```

Where `num_words` is approximately 100k and `num_documents` is approximately 35k.
Also worth mentioning that the type is `double`

Edit2:

Relevant flags:

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx128g
-d64
```

Comment: What are the data type and dimensions? Can you show the declaration?

Comment: Give us the -Xms and -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize ...

Comment: @venergiac See edit. I dont have MaxPermSize set (didn't know what it was)

Comment: How do you set the Xmx128g while u have just 16G of RAM!!!

Comment: @JUBA My HDD is pretty big

Comment: Its not about HDD its about Memory!!. see my answer.

Comment: @JUBA http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging - "Paging is an important part of virtual memory implementation in most contemporary general-purpose operating systems, allowing them to use disk storage for data that does not fit into physical random-access memory (RAM)"

Comment: @Shmoopy in this case yes you could use as much as you can from the disk if you have set that much of your HDD as Paging.

Comment: @Shmoopy: Your process doesn't have 2^64 bytes available. It's limited by the size of pagefile / swap space. How much did you allocate to that? What operating system are you using anyway?

Comment: @Codo You're right. I'm using Windows 8 and it's set to 32GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM works as native process, in this respect: JVM requests memory from OS that can allocate it either in RAM in swap.

The memory you can allocate in java does not depend on your RAM but on command line option `-Xmx` you specify when you are running your JVM. If it is not enough memory in RAM JVM receives it from swap and (I believe) even does not know about that.

However,

- in some opearating system (Windows XP) the limit is 4G.
- the heap in the JVM is not designed to run off disk.
- swap is limited.

If you need to work with large data you need to work with BigMemory products (EhCache or Terracotta).

Finally, run jvisualvm or with the `-verbose:gc` prameter to see the heap allocation.

Comment: Is there any reference to "the heap in the JVM is not designed to run off disk." ?

Comment: It is not a real specification, but it depends from JVM implementation. Generaly speking JVM needs continuos memory which is NOT guaranteed from swap or 32bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

Here some description:

```
Xms -> the init memory that should be allocated in the start up in MB.
Xmx -> the Max amount of memory that your application can get in MB e.g Xmx2048m.
-XX:MaxNewSize= -> the max S1 and S2 memory size
-XX:NewSize= -> init S1 and S2 size
```

so in your case if you want to allocate memory as much as you can, so you need to say for example `16 * 1024 = 16384 or 16g` and the `-XX:MaxNewSize= and -XX:NewSize=` set it by 40% of your Xmx

Comment: Notice the `m` after `2048m`? That means megabyte. Likewise, you can use `g` for gigabyte, so `16g` would mean 16 gigabyte, the same as `16384m` (16384 megabyte).

Answer (score 1):

A few things you should know.

- Managed memory doesn't swap very well.  In fact it usually results in your application dying or your OS locking up (esp windows you have to power cycle if even 10% of your heap is swapped)
- The heap is divided into multiple regions and it will not resize always as you might expect.  Normally it will scale these regions together e.g. it will make the young and tenured spaces 1:8 i.e. you cannot easily grab almost all the heap at once. I would try a 192 GB maximum heap.
- Most advanced processes support 48-bit address spaces or 256 TB of virtual memory and only 40-bit of actual memory (1 TB per processors)
- the `-d64` only works on Solaris.

In short you need about 256 GB of main memory and a large heap you really consider what you are doing.  Accessing memory randomly is up to one million times faster than accessing disk space and this means not only is it one million times slower, but it is unlikely to work at all.

What you can do is use off heap memory, and if you really know what you are doing, you can make this work and be perhaps only 100x slower than having the memory you need. esp if you use a fast SSD for swap or your matrix is sparse is just the right ways.